# Magento search Configurable product showing on simple product name

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, search, catalogsearch

These are my settings

In Configuration Catalog search is set to `Fulltext`.

In Attributes only `name` is searchable.

Configurable products are `catalog-search` while associated simple products are set to `Not visible indivisually`.

Configurable Product name is `Violet Diamond` and one of simple product name is `Blackberry Diamond`.

So When I am searching for `Blackberry`, `Violet Diamond` comes up. This should not happen.

When I changes the name of simple product `Blackberry Diamond` to something else then it works and nothing comes up in the search.

Anybody have any idea.

Comment: what magento version?

Comment: Magento 1.9.3.1

Comment: This is behavior is correct and default /natural . For configurable product search   parent product will only searched because child product visibility is not visible individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as Pramod Kharade says in the comments, this is default behavior.
The method `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext::_rebuildStoreIndex` that is called when the full text search index is rebuild calls this.

```
$productChildren = $this->_getProductChildrenIds($productData['entity_id'],
                    $productData['type_id'], $websiteId);
```

which retrieves the simple products for the configurable, grouped and bundle products and adds the searchable attribute values of these child products to the parent product search fields.
If you don't like this behaviour you can rewrite the method `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext::_getProductChildrenIds` and make it return `null`.

Comment: Thanks Marius, Its correct that its Magento default behaviour but its a client update and some clients are stupid :)